# save python chinese into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I already use `dict[key]=dict[key].encode('utf-8')` in python,
and set mysql default character like this :

```
--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                  |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.6.29-osx10.8-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

but still can't get right chinese, what I get is like  `å°˜çš„ç©ºé—´` .what's wrong?

I searched some answer and add `charset="utf8`         `self.db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","QQ",charset="utf8")`

get error :

```
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE8\\xAF\\x84\\xE8\\xAF\\xAD...' for column 'content' at row 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched error 1366 ,and find database collation doesn't match the collation I put in MySQL. so I do this:`show full columns from table_name;` find row that don't use utf-8 encode .then `alter table table_name change name name varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci not null default '';`
it works.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as correct so that people can see your question is solved without having to open it.

Comment: I try to accept my own answer but it said I should wait 2days before  I can do that.